# Single-row subquery returns more than one row- update with nested selects and substr

Tags: oracle, select, nested, subquery, substring

I'm trying to write a query for a table that needs to update certain records based on certain perameters.  I have several nested selects and a couple of nested substrings which I imagine are what is making it difficult for me to troubleshoot.  I solved a couple of these **ORA-01427: single row sub-query returns more than one row** problems already, but I can't seem to find this one.  Essentially what the script is doing is taking two columns from a record and updating them based another record contained within a different table based on a number of different criteria.  Below is the current code I am using:

```
UPDATE CMC_SBEL_ELIG_ENT p
SET (p.CSPI_ID, p.SBEL_EFF_DT) =
(SELECT co.new_plan, co.ch_dt
   FROM sbsb_plan_conv co, cmc_sbel_elig_ent p
   WHERE co.ch_dt > p.sbel_eff_dt
     and co.ch_dt < current_date
     AND co.new_plan <> p.CSPI_ID
     AND co.sbsb_ck = p.sbsb_ck
     AND p.cspi_id IN co.OLD_PLAN
     and p.SBEL_ELIG_TYPE IN ('tm','ce','TM','CE')
     )
WHERE (p.cspd_cat IN (
   select unique substr(o.old_plan, 1, 1) 
      from facets_ws.sbsb_plan_conv o
      where 
        substr(o.old_plan, 1, 1) IN (
            select substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1)   
            from sbsb_plan_conv y, cmc_sbel_elig_ent u
            where y.sbsb_ck = u.sbsb_ck
              AND (p.SBEL_ELIG_TYPE IN ('tm','ce','TM','CE'))

              and ((substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) = 'M'
                and substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) != 'R'
                and substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) != 'D') 

                or (substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) = 'R'
                and substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) != 'M'
                and substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) != 'D')

                or (substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) = 'D'
                and substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) != 'R'
                and substr(y.new_plan, 1, 1) != 'M'))

            and o.sbsb_ck = p.sbsb_ck)
      )
  );
```

Now when I run the individual queries on the two select statements, they all return definite unique values.  So I'm fairly certain they are not the issue.

Comment: Your first subquery is returning multiple rows for sure. Please use `MERGE` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try executing the following query :-

```
SELECT count(co.new_plan)
  FROM sbsb_plan_conv co, cmc_sbel_elig_ent p
WHERE co.ch_dt > p.sbel_eff_dt
 and co.ch_dt < current_date
 AND co.new_plan <> p.CSPI_ID
 AND co.sbsb_ck = p.sbsb_ck
 AND p.cspi_id IN co.OLD_PLAN
 and p.SBEL_ELIG_TYPE IN ('tm','ce','TM','CE')
 group by co.new_plan;
```

If the above returns more than one row or if it returns a count more than one, then you might need to change the query to either do a DISTINCT / MIN / use ROWNUM or some other technique.